# Induction vs BLDC generators

Tags: ac, brushless-dc-motor, generator, induction-motor, power-generation

I am doing research on wind generation to power local equipment. A sub-project involves choosing the generator and defining the control method.

I am interested in understanding why one motor type is preferred over the other (or the pros/cons of each one).

The main design requirement is having a generation power of 500 W to 1 kW that can handle high RPM (>3600 RPM)

The other important factors for the generator are:

- Ability to handle varying speed
- Long-term reliability
- Ability to control top speed
- Price

From my research I lean towards BLDC due to low generation requirement, but I am looking for additional opinions.

An additional question: What type of control would be needed?

Comment: When talking about wind power, there are multiple types of induction machine that can be used. Are you talking about a simple induction machine, or a doubly-fed induction machine? The latter is more complicated, but also more common for wind turbine generators as it works over a wider range of operating speeds.

Comment: For such a small turbine output with a varying speed requirement you're probably best off converting whatever comes from the tower to DC and then inverting it. BLDC with a fixed frequency output does not satisfy all your requirements.

Comment: I was referring to a simple induction machine. I believe with both the simple induction and BLDC there would need to be conversion to DC power before sending to equipment.